# lightbox not working on IE8

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, lightbox

Hello my company bought a woo theme  WP and the lightbox works in firefox but not on IE8.

I saw some post here that is javascript related, but I dont want to mess with it until a get a good guidance to find the issue.

Our site is [www.fiestatax.com](http://www.fiestatax.com) , click on the small thumbs in the main page using IE
any help will be appreciated

Sincerely,Jim

Answer (score 1):

The images you are linking to are [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) images, which IE can't display.

Save them in RGB format.